How to control the creation of NSTextElement in NSTextContentStorage?
I have a NSAttributedString which contains a attachment.
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* ps = [NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attri = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"12345" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:ps}];
    ImageAttachment* attachment = [ImageAttachment new];
    attachment.textLayoutManager = self.layoutManager;
    
    [attri appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment]];

And I want to using TextKit2 to custom a UIView class which may layout this attributed string  like this:
======
12345
image attachment
======
So I think the first step will be create two NSTextElements with the attributed string (one element for 12345, and one for attachment)
But in fact , when I set the attributedstring to the NSTextContentStorage and call enumerateTextElementsFromLocation immediately.
    self.contentStorage.textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:richContent];
    [self.contentStorage enumerateTextElementsFromLocation:self.contentStorage.documentRange.location options:NSTextContentManagerEnumerationOptionsNone
                                                usingBlock:^BOOL(NSTextElement * _Nonnull element) {
        NSLog(@"element:%@",element);
        return YES
        ;
    }];

the delegate method will be called for create a NSTextElement
- (nullable NSTextElement *)textContentManager:(NSTextContentManager *)textContentManager textElementAtLocation:(id <NSTextLocation>)location
{
    NSLog(@"manager:%@,textElementAtLocation:%@",textContentManager,location);

    return [[NSTextElement alloc] initWithTextContentManager:textContentManager];
}

But in fact , this method will be called only for once ,with the location set to 0. and so it seems to impossible to create element for text and attachment seperately?
Any way to do it ?
